# What is the Cleanup badge awarded for?

Tags: discussion, badges

The description of the "Cleanup" badge simply states that is awarded upon your "First rollback." What is a rollback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rollback involves reversing an edit (or multiple edits) on a post to a previous version.

All posts edited outside of a (currently) 5 minute window will display an "edited X time ago" link to the left of the post author's badge.  If you click that link, you will see a history of edits to that post.  One of the options, for all but the last edit, is "rollback."

[image: The rollback option.]

Note: those are two separate options, `edit` and `rollback`.